# Полоски между основным контентом и фоном

Tags: css

Верстаю макет и хочу сделать вот такие [полоски](https://puu.sh/EQKTf/d8e80609af.png)

Сделал [таким образом](https://codepen.io/oximon/pen/LYExzQx), но появляется горизонтальный скролл и при уменьшении экрана белая полоска увеличивается.. Как это можно исправить?

```
  <div class="footer"> content </div>



.footer {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 38px 35px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.footer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  left: -1020px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: -1020px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  height: 10vh;
  background: pink;
}

.strip {
  position: relative;
}

.strip::before,
.strip::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(20vw - 10px);
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.strip::before {
  right: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.strip::after {
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="section strip"></section>
</div>
```